# What is the best way to restrict access to html admin pages in my case?

Tags: java, apache, security

I am developing an application as a separate RESTful server on Java (Spring) and separately located (currently I got up Apache Http web server) html pages with js scripts.

I have some public pages for all users and some admin html pages. My target is to secure admin html pages. Public htmls are placed under 'user/' directory, admin under 'admin/' directory.

I would prefer to manage users I have on the java server, but the problem here is that I cannot secure these pages with my java server as admin pages located with other pages on the Apache server. I thought about some javascript-related security (use script on admin pages to call some server endpoint and check if user admin, then do redirect), but it feels like this would not be safe at least because js can be disabled and then the page will be loaded anyway. I see that Apache has some authentication configurations, as I see it is also possible to connect Apache authentication to a database and possibly also connect my java application to it, to use one database for Apache and Java servers. By now it is the best option in my opinion.

This project is not very serious and it is for learning, but I would still like to figure out the best solution in this case. What do you think, if there is better option for authentication if I have Java RESTful server and some front end separately?

Comment: I would not suggest it as the native Apache authentication dialog on browsers look very raw and obtrusive. You should find other options for eg JWT

Comment: more details pls, how would you see it? @simply-put

Comment: as described, problem is that html pages stored on apache http, I use it as frontend web server, so I should implement authentication on apache or find other solutions, otherwise max what I can do is make some js scripts (that can be disabled) and just make rest endpints secure, but still somebody will can access pages even if them are empty and all endpoints are secured.
What I want to see is that if somebody non-authenticated access admin page, he gets redirected or refused by server-side.
Maybe, I should use something else instead of apache? @simply-put